# unable to summarize time difference and size of client with uniformity

Tags: bash

I am having tough time in getting time difference and size with uniform code like MB or GB or TB for entire client backup duration.

Below is my command:

```
mminfo -v -q "group=testgroup1,savetime>=02/17/2022,savetime<=02/18/2022" -r \
    "savetime,level,totalsize,volume,vmname,client,sscreate(20),sscomp(20)" -xc,
```

- `-q` is for query
- `-r` is to retrieve params from query
- group contains the clients
- savetime is day of backup
- level is level of backup
- totalsize is size of backup in bytes
- volume is the name of volume where data is stored
- vmname gives the name of vm
- client gives name of client , both vmname and client are one and same depends on type of backup.
- sscreate(20) gives start time of backup
- sscomp(20) gives end time of backup

o/p of my command looks like this

```
17/02/22,incr,4853101080,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:18,17/02/22 20:40:45
17/02/22,incr,404305556,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:15,17/02/22 20:27:34
17/02/22,incr,645786660,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:17,17/02/22 20:27:30
17/02/22,incr,4,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:45,17/02/22 20:27:47
17/02/22,incr,4,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:16,17/02/22 20:27:19
17/02/22,incr,4,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:46,17/02/22 20:27:48
17/02/22,incr,4,volume.001,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:28:05,17/02/22 20:28:08
17/02/22,incr,4,volume.002,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:48,17/02/22 20:27:51
17/02/22,incr,6085356,volume.002,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:42:26,17/02/22 20:42:51
17/02/22,incr,53328,volume.004,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:43:13,17/02/22 20:43:22
17/02/22,incr,4,volume.004,,testclient1,17/02/22 20:27:34,17/02/22 20:27:37
```

for each drive/mount point of a backup we have an entry in output in each line. Am able to sumup of size of data backed up per each client on a day but unable to get the logic for calculating time difference for backup for a client on one particular day. can someone help me with this?

logic which i used:(awk is where  i started filtering the data)

```
printf "show name\n p type:nsr group\n" |
    nsradmin -i - |
    grep -v ^$ |
    cut -d: -f2- |
    cut -d\; -f1 |
    sort -u |
    perl -pe 's/\ //' |
    while read grp;do
        mminfo -q "group=$grp,savetime>02/12/2022 16:00,savetime<02/13/2022 16:00,level=full" \
             -r "savetime,level,totalsize,volume,vmname,client,sscreate(20),sscomp(20)" \
             -xc, 2>/dev/null |
           awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{if($5=="")$5=$6;else $5=$5;print}' |
           awk -F, '$5 != "vm_name" {a[$5","$2]+=$3;b[$5","$2]++;OFS=FS}
                     END{for (v in a) print v,b[v],a[v]}'|
           while read j;do echo $grp,$j;
       done
    done
```

o/p from code looks like this:

```
testgroup1,testclient1,full,11,65959975044
```

Comment: o/ p normally looks like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting to fold all the post processing logic into a single `gawk` (standard Linux `awk`) script .

#### script.awk

```
function timestamp(dateStr) {
  formatedStr = gensub(/([[:digit:]]{2})\/([[:digit:]]{2})\/([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})/, 
                       "20\\3 \\2 \\1 \\4 \\5 \\6", 1, dateStr);
  # from: DD/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
  # to:   YYYY MM DD HH MM SS
  return mktime(formatedStr);
}
BEGIN {
  minStartTime = 9999999999999999999999;
}
$5 == "" {
  $5 = $6;
}
{
  accumulatedDailyStorage[$5","$2] += $3;
  accumulatedDailyTime[$5","$2] += (timestamp($8) - timestamp($7));
  startTime = timestamp($7);
  minStartTime  = (startTime < minStartTime) ? startTime : minStartTime ; 
  endTime = timestamp($8);
  maxEndTime = (endTime > maxEndTime) ? endTime : maxEndTime ;
  accumulatedDailyCount[$5","$2]++;
}
END {
  for (clientName in accumulatedDailyStorage) {
    print clientName, accumulatedDailyStorage[clientName], accumulatedDailyCount[clientName], accumulatedDailyTime[clientName], (maxEndTime - minStartTime);
  }
}
```

#### Output:

```
awk -F, -f script.awk input.1.txt
testclient1,incr 5909332004 11 889 6666
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it Dudi boy. For accumulated daily time the logic which am trying should be calculated using time diff of highest time value in complete time and lowest time value in start time of particular client. .That gives the total duration backup happened.

Comment: Updated script with requested logic, did not test it. Hope it it make sense to you.